# Why does main thread here doesn't wait for t2? Here the output is always more than 20000 but not consistent

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package org.multithreading.basics;

public class ThreadJoin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Counter counter = new Counter();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(counter);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(counter);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers counted =" + counter.getCount());
    }

}

class Counter implements Runnable {

    private int count;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
            count++;
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Here the output is always >20000 and <40000 and always random value. So in the above code, main tread is waiting for t1 to complete but why not for t2, though the join is there on t1 as well as t2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code waits for both threads to finish, 4000 `++` statements will have been executed!

BUT you need to understand how threads work, how their variable access works, what `volatile` and non-volatile variables are, how synchronisation works, why they differ and why the results you see are perfectly reasonable and 100% expected.

`x++` is *basically* `x = x + 1` (this is not a precise explanation but the general thing that is happening here) => if both threads run that statement at the same time you will lose one increment since both read `x = 123`, both call `123 + 1` => `124` and then both assign `124` to `x` => two increments called but the value is only increased by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ignored to think that both the threads can execute increment step at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As per above code, we have called t1.start() and t2.start() at same time so, both the thread will starting executing task defined inside run method but in next line we have call t1.join therefore main thread will wait for completion of t1 method but still t2 thread is executing in parallel (both threads are reading same count value and update it at same time hence it actually increased once instead of two times) once we called t2.join() then main thread will wait for completion of t2 thread hence we can see output in range of >20000 and <40000

in case you want to fix this data inconsistency issue modify your code as below

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        count++;
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
```

Here counter is the common object passed as a reference to both the threads.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    count++;
}
```

The ***count*** variable is incremented by both threads working together.

So, It is illusioned that the main thread waits for t1 to count just above 20000 and terminates without waiting for t2 to complete.

In fact, the *main* thread waits until both thread increment ***count*** just above 20000.

**The above explanation is for main thread not waiting for t2.**

The ***count*** is accessed in an unsynchronized way. 
The expression `count++ equivalent to count = count+1`

Two operations assignment and addition are done in parallel. So, value incremented by t1 may be overwritten by t2. this value will not be in sequence and not constant during execution. So, Every time value of count will vary.

Comment: *"In fact, the main thread waits until both thread increment count just above 20000."*, the main thread does not care about counting. It may even happen that the result is less than 20000 in the end if too many operations of one thread are overwritten by one operation of the other thread.

Comment: The explanation was for "Why does main thread here doesn't wait for t2?"